# when using a rollover image to submit a form, my validation is ignored

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, rollover

I'm using JQ and CSS to validate a form, and in conjunction with some JS I'm hiding part of the form until the user clicks continue. However I can't get the styling to be applied to the continue or join now buttons in the form

You can see my example here [example1](http://www.secklow.com/form/form.asp)

When you click continue, the second part of the form appears and then you can click join and the form validattion process kicks in. However the 'join now' button at the very bottom is the styling that *should* be applied to my buttons, but isn't (I can't work out why and I've tried everything I can think of)

so, I decided that instead of using CSS to style the buttons, I would use a rollover image. This works for styling the buttons, but when I try to submit the form, no validation is performed

you can see this here [example2](http://www.secklow.com/form/form2.asp)

can anyone work out how I can accomplish either 1 or 2 (ie styling the buttons or rollover image with validation)

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it is HTML5, try using `<button></button>` instead of a link

```
<button style="width:90px;height:31px;border:0;" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image3','','joinnowro.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onclick="submit()" href="#"><img style="width:90px;height:31px;" id="Image3" name="Image3" src="http://www.secklow.com/form/joinnow.jpg" style="width: 90px; height: 31px;"></button>
```

almost looks OK - not sure why there is a bit of button to the left

---

For straight html:

1. NEVER call anything submit
2. If you submit using script, the onsubmit event handler is NOT called

So

```
function submitForm(){
  if (validate(document.register)) document.register.submit()
  return false;
}
```

and

```
<a href="#" onclick="return submitForm()"
```

Answer (score 0):

For example 1...

1) Remove `#register .formbutton1` declaration from form.asp
2) Remove `#register fieldset input` declaration from formstyle.css
3) Add the following to `formstyle.css`

```
input.formbutton1  {
    background:#2c2a29; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:16px; 
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin-top:0px;
}

input.formbutton1:hover {background:#C68DB6;}
```

As you can see above, you have specified the behaviour of the button in multiple places. It works fine when I cleared them and added it to `formstyle.css`.